# default values to hidden fields

Tags: sharepoint

I created a content type that uses a CheckBox that has a default value.  When I save documents of that content type the default value behaves as expected.  If I make that checkBox hidden and create a new document with the content type it is not assigning the default value.  When I look at the XML results from a search that returns all documents in that content type the document created with the hidden field on it doesn't even have a node for the hidden field.

Is there something special that I need to do to get the hidden field to take it's default value?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the answer of your question. But you can make it a normal (not hidden) column, and hide it from the forms with a simple JavaScript code. You can add a content editor Web part to embed the necessary JS code to the form.

Comment: where all i would do this what about edit in datasheet mode ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can hide the column easily in the datasheet mode, but you can hide the datasheet mode menu if it's not required.